# docker-compose yaml.scanner.ScannerError

Tags: docker, apache-spark, docker-compose

cannot run the following docker-compose with the below docker-compose code, and it seem all the code work fine, and i pull the image to my server already, but it still not work !

```
master:
    image: sequenceiq/spark:1.4.0
    hostname: master
    ports:
    - "4040:4040"
    - "8042:8042"
    - "7077:7077"
    - "8088:8088"
    - "8080:8080"
    restart: always
        deploy:
        resources:
            limits:
            cpus: '0.50'
            memory: 1024M
            reservations:
            cpus: '0.25'
            memory: 256M
    command: bash /usr/local/spark/sbin/start-master.sh && ping localhost > /dev/null

worker:
    image: sequenceiq/spark:1.4.0
    links:
        - master:master
    expose:
        - "8081"
    restart: always
    command: bash /usr/local/spark/sbin/start-slave.sh spark://master:7077 && ping localhost >/dev/null
```

Error Messages:

```
RROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning for the 
next token found character '\t' that cannot start any token in "./docker-compose.yml", line 2, column 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker-compose` is written in python, and `\t` in python means `tab`.

So, you error means you have `tab` in your `docker-compose.yaml` which used for indent, this is forbidden, detail see [this](https://yaml.org/faq.html):

> **Why does YAML forbid tabs?**
>
> Tabs have been outlawed since they are treated differently by different editors and tools. And since indentation is so critical to proper interpretation of YAML, this issue is just too tricky to even attempt. Indeed Guido van Rossum of Python has acknowledged that allowing TABs in Python source is a headache for many people and that were he to design Python again, he would forbid them.

So, you need to check your `docker-compose.yaml` to change all indent to `space`.